# parse line-separated json objects in html table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I can't change json format. The data store in new line.
json file:

```
{"ProgMode":"on","wait_h":"5","wait_m":"5","output":"1"}
{"ProgMode":"off","wait_h":"10","wait_m":"10","output":"2"}
```

I using below code but without bracket ([]) in json file, it doesn't work.

```
    var ReqJson = new XMLHttpRequest();
function response(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        const dbParam = JSON.stringify({table:"ProgramView",limit:20});
        let text = "<table class='table my-0'>"
        for (let x in myObj) {
        text += '<tr><td>' + myObj[x].wait_h + ':' + myObj[x].wait_m + ':' + myObj[x].output + '</td></tr>';
        }
        text += "</table>"    
        document.getElementById("dynamic_table").innerHTML = text;
    }
}

function ProccessConfig(){
    ReqJson.open("POST", "Programs.json", true);
    ReqJson.onreadystatechange = response;
    ReqJson.send()
}
ProccessConfig();
```

So how can I parse json that is stored with new lines and without comma and brackets?

Comment: `const validJSON = \`[${this.responseText.split("\n").join(",")}]\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to split and map, it is to heavy for this case, try this

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(`[${this.responseText.replaceAll("}\n","},")}]`);
```

this is a little more complicated, but much more reliable,since it is not using any special symbols

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(`[{${this.responseText.substring(1).replaceAll("{",",{")}]`);
```

Comment: return this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 120

Comment: @MSaberi It is working properly on my mashine, but maybe your json file is different from json you posted. Try this var myObj = JSON.parse(`[${responseText.replaceAll("\n",",")}]`);

Comment: @MSaberi Or you can try my updated answer if it is still not working

Comment: thanks. your latest update worked fine. and the advantage is work with any empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the input text in rows and then 'JSON.parse' the single row.

```
let myObj = this.responseText.split('\n')
  .filter(line => line !== "")
  .map(JSON.parse);
```

Example based on your string:

```js
let text = `{"ProgMode":"on","wait_h":"5","wait_m":"5","output":"1"}
{"ProgMode":"off","wait_h":"10","wait_m":"10","output":"2"}
`

let myObj = text.split('\n')
  .filter(line => line !== "")
  .map(JSON.parse);
console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: Nice one. Better than mine

Comment: return this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @MSaberi the code works on your example string

Comment: 3rd party devices fill json file with extra enter (/n) end of file. when I remove it manually everything fine. any solution to remove automatically empty line from end of the file?

Comment: @MSaberi updated the response, you can use filter to ignore empty lines